# Running Jenkins behind Apache 2.2 issue

Tags: apache, authentication, jenkins, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I need to configure Jenkins behind Apache. For this purpose I installed Apache 2.2 using httpd-2.2.25-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8y.msi.
Now I have configured jenkins with -

```
--httpPort=8084 --prefix=/jenkins (inside jenkins.xml)
```

The `securityRealm` for Jenkins is (I am using LDAP authentication):

```
  <securityRealm class="hudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm" plugin="ldap@1.11">
    <server>ldap://ldap.myserver.com:1234</server>
    <rootDN>DC=blah-blah,DC=blah</rootDN>
    <inhibitInferRootDN>false</inhibitInferRootDN>
    <userSearchBase></userSearchBase>
    <userSearch>SAMAccountName={0}</userSearch>
    <groupSearchFilter></groupSearchFilter>
    <groupMembershipStrategy class="jenkins.security.plugins.ldap.FromGroupSearchLDAPGroupMembershipStrategy">
      <filter></filter>
    </groupMembershipStrategy>
    <managerDN>email@mycompany.com</managerDN>
    <managerPasswordSecret>XXXX</managerPasswordSecret>
    <disableMailAddressResolver>false</disableMailAddressResolver>
    <displayNameAttributeName>displayname</displayNameAttributeName>
    <mailAddressAttributeName>mail</mailAddressAttributeName>
    <userIdStrategy class="jenkins.model.IdStrategy$CaseInsensitive"/>
    <groupIdStrategy class="jenkins.model.IdStrategy$CaseInsensitive"/>
  </securityRealm>
```

The name of the server where Apache and Jenkins are hosted is : http://abchost/.
Jenkins is hosted at : http://abchost:8084/jenkins.

Now I need to configure Apache server in such a way that, when I enter http://abchost/jenkins in browser it a Proxy should work in between and it should forward the request to http://abchost:8084/jenkins and again, get the result from jenkins and display the result at : http://abchost/jenkins.

For this I have configured Apache like this:

```
NameVirtualHost abchost:80
Listen 80

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
AllowEncodedSlashes On

<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName abchost.com
  ServerAdmin admin@abchost.com

  ProxyPass /downloads !
  Alias /downloads "d:\myPath1"

  <Directory "d:\myPath2">
    # Don't allow editing the main repository site.
    Options -Indexes
  </Directory>  

  <Directory "d:\myPath3">
    # Remove 'Parent Directory' link from the site.
    # IndexIgnore ..
    # 
    Options +Indexes
    # List file names which will be opened automatically when the folder is opened.
    DirectoryIndex index.html toc.html

    IndexOptions FancyIndexing HTMLTable FoldersFirst SuppressDescription
  </Directory>  


    <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Proxy>

  # Jenkins via HTTP.
  ProxyPass /jenkins/ http:/abchost:8084/jenkins/ nocanon
  ProxyPassReverse /jenkins http://abchost:8084/jenkins/

</VirtualHost>
```

After this configuration, I am able to login in jenkins using http:/abchost:8084/jenkins/, but, not using http:/abchost/jenkins/.

Point to  note  is:

1. When I am logging in http:/abchost/jenkins/ using proper user id and pswd, it looks like the page refreshes and blank login page appears again.
2. When I am logging in http:/abchost/jenkins/ using wrong user id and pswd combination, it shows message that LDAP authentication failed.

Can anyone please enlighten me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any help from anyone? still stuck with this issue.

Comment: I have installed Apaceh 32 bit version in 64 bit OS. Is it possible that the issue is cased by this?